Problem of remaining residual spikes only at lag 10 (!) in the PACF plot after using ARIMA (in fable, R)
As shown in the PACF plot attached, a 0.5 magnitude autocorrelation spike at lag ten remains after fitting the model with ARIMA using the fable package, following the FPP3 book.

The response variable is the Trend component derived from an STL decomposition of daily pollen densities from 11 years, but only 65 continuous days each year (the pollinic season; I reindexed the data to use a numeric time index; no calendar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78928776/how-to-deal-with-summer-only-daily-data-for-stl-and-time-series-modelling-in-r).
Orders: The 'search' option selects a (p = 2, 1, q = 3) ARIMA structure, but the same happens with a model with pre-selected orders (1,1,1), which have similar AICs.
Also, a suggestive pattern is visible in the innovation residuals plot (attached), where the majority of points are around zero, but every 10 lags, one or two points spike. Including external regressors does not affect the problems in the residuals.
I wonder where should I look to improve this model?
This is the code for the models, AICs and plot:
fit <- tseq |>
    model(arima111 = ARIMA(trend ~ pdq(1,1,1)),
          search = ARIMA(trend, stepwise=FALSE))

 glance(fit)|>
   arrange(AICc) |>
   select(.model:AIC)
 
 fit |>
   select(arima111) |>
   gg_tsresiduals()

A similar pattern appears in the PACF plot of a nlme::gls model with corARMA (p=0, q=1). A corARMA(1,1) model does not converge. fable::ARIMA seems to converge fine, but the autocorrelation is not completely corrected, as mentioned.


It's not normally a good idea to model trend with an ARIMA model, as the trend variable is smooth and ARIMA models need randomness. I'd work with the original data.
Your ACF plot suggests either seasonality of period 10 (unlikely with daily data) or strong cyclic behaviour with average length cycle around 10. So you probably need to try some more sophisticated models than the default settings in ARIMA() allow. Try increasing the maximum AR order, and set stepwise to FALSE.


I have two questions (1 and 2) inspired by reading your FPP2 textbook. Perhaps you could take a look at them or at least the first one?

I appreciate the rapid response, thanks a lot!

Yes, the Trend is certainly smooth. I tried the same with the remainder, and the residuals seem ok.
What would you suggest in order to evaluate long-term (stl-Trend) separatedly from short-term (stl-Remainder)? since their relation with meteo variables is sometimes opposing. I intend to build an explanatory AND predictive model.
(However, I wonder on the correctness of using the same predictors for the trend and the remainder, since their predicted values will ultimately be summed, and added to the seasonal deterministic stl-component.)



I tried setting the AR order up to 10 (with stepwise = FALSE, order_constraint = TRUE), but the residual patterns remain the same.

The smoothness of the Trend component could be somehow generating this characteristic spikes every ten points?
